# Discover the last word in excel

Tags: excel

I have a column with names and I want to return the last name.
Example of the sheet:

```
Name             Last Name    
Henry Cavill   
Ben Affleck      
Gal Gadot
Amy Lou Adams
```

I can return the first name using this formula
**=LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1)** but I don't know how to do this for the last name.

I know how to do this in VBA mode, but I want to do this in excel too.

Comment: Same logic `=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(" ",A2))`

Comment: It's work only if the name has two words.

Comment: @Vinicius Do you have an example with not "two Words"?

Comment: @reporter I edit the question includes the name "Amy Lou Adams"

Comment: @reporter yes, in this case I want to return just the last word "Adams", if I using the sentence that Alex suggests it will return "Lou Adams".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formula which will always return last word from a cell value.

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),LEN(A2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your edit, ff you need to get everything after the first name use,

```
=MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)+1,LEN(A2))
```

So `Amy Lou Adams` will return `Lou Adams`

EDIT

Alex K.'s answer is correct for return the last name. If what you mean by 'only two names' I can only assume you mean if there is only 1 name?

If so you can use the following `=IFERROR(RIGHT(TRIM(A2),LEN(A2)-FIND(" ",TRIM(A2))), TRIM(A2))`

The `TRIM` ensures you don't get an error if you had trailing spaces at the end of the sentence and will return the following

```
Name             Last Name    
Amy Lou Adams    Adams
Amy Adams        Adams
Amy              Amy
```

Comment: Thanks for answer it, but I want to return just the last word, in that case just the word "Adams".

Comment: Alex K. gave you that answer with `=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(" ",A2))` and you said it was wrong, but thats exactly what you need then.